# Can't run apps without sudo

Tags: permissions, root, spotify, clementine

I do my research and can't find anything useful, maybe I'm using the wrong keywords, nvm.

if I try to run `spotify` for example I got `"Unable to initialize the storage of temporary files"` error, but if I go `sudo spotify` it works like a charm.

Same thing on clementine got `"librarybackend attempt to write a readonly database unable to fetch row"` but if I run `sudo clementine` works great.

Now I know the power of `sudo` so, how can make this work without typing `sudo everytime`?

I was thinking adding to group users, but dunno how to do it or if it safe to do this, on the `spotify` folder y even `chmod 777` the file but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess that at some point, files in your home directory became owned by `root` (because of misuse of `sudo`). Try `chown`ing them back:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~ -R
```

Answer (score 0):

Change owner folder of spotify locate in `.cache` of your user and change the ownership:

```
cd /home/YOURUSER/.cache

sudo chown USER:USER spotify -R
```